# How to reveal and hide hyperlinks within a HTML list using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, list, hyperlink

I am designing a website and have adapted a simple javascript script to display sub-links under every menu title.

The menu titles are stored in a list and each one houses individual hyperlinks and are revealed using a CSS file with the following classes:

```
.hidden {display: none;}
.unhidden {display: block;}
```

Based on this javascript function:

```
function unhide(liID) {
         var item = document.getElementById(liID);
         if (item) {
            item.className=(item.className=='hidden')?'unhidden':'hidden';
         }
        }
```

Here is a sample of the HTML file:

```
<a href="javascript:unhide('menu1');">First Menu</a>
<li id="menu1" class="hidden"> 
    <ul class="subMenus">
        <li>Sub menu 1 item 1</li>
        <li>Sub menu 1 item 2</li>
        <li>Sub menu 1 item 3</li>
        <li>Sub menu 1 item 4</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<a href="javascript:unhide('menu2');">Second Menu</a>
<li id="menu2" class="hidden"> 
    <ul class="subMenus">
        <li>Sub menu 2 item 1</li>
        <li>Sub menu 2 item 2</li>
        <li>Sub menu 2 item 3</li>
        <li>Sub menu 2 item 4</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

The code works and performs well. But with the way it is coded, once a menu has been opened it must be clicked again for it to collapse. Otherwise the lists get really long and crowded after 3 or 4 menus are opened.

My question is...., what is the code required in the javascript to close the previously opened menu as it opens a new one to save space?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For keeping previous active menu in global variable you can hide previously selected menu, following js may helpful for you

```
var activemnu="";
function unhide(liID) {

  var item = document.getElementById(liID);
  if(liID!=activemnu && activemnu!="")
  {
     var activeitem= document.getElementById(activemnu);
     activeitem.className= 'hidden';
  }

  if (item) {
     item.className=(item.className=='hidden')?'unhidden':'hidden';
  }
  activemnu=liID;
```

}

Comment: Can't thank you enough.
That worked like a treat.

I appreciate the help. :)

@alex thanks for your assistance too. :D

Answer (score 1):

I believe something like this should work, although it's not recommended to put the event handlers inline, you'll actually want to set them with the `addEventListener()` function in your javascript:

```
<a href="javascript:void()" id="menu1" onMouseOver="javascript:unhide('menu1');" onMouseOut="javascript:unhide('menu1')">First Menu</a>
```

This is how you would set the handlers without making them inline:

```
function unhide(liID) {
  return function () {
    var item = document.getElementById(liID);
    if (item) {
      item.className = (item.className == 'hidden') ? 'unhidden' : 'hidden';
    }
  }
}

var menu1 = document.getElementById("menu1");
menu1.addEventListener("mouseover", unhide('menu1'), true);
menu1.addEventListener("mouseout", unhide('menu2'), true);
```

Comment: I tried your answer and when my mouse hovers over a menu, it appears and disappears when the mouse is gone.

I can confirm it works, but I was looking for a click adaptation.

Because when the cursor leaves the menu title into the list, the menu shuts as the mouse isn't hovering over the title anymore.

I have very little knowledge about javascript I'm afraid...

Thanks for the help though, I appreciate it. :)

Comment: @revxaisks You could change `onMouseOut` to be `onClick` and the menu won't close unless you click it, or hover over it again.

Comment: The list still has the possibility of getting crowded unless the user hover over it or click it again.
It's half and half right now. :D

Perhaps this is beneficial?
http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?234966-CSS-menu-with-onclick-instead-of-hover&s=04c01cd599a17d738eb0d53a3910f2d4&p=1111325#post1111325

That was the first solution I tried. It works perfectly, only the webpage loads with the menus all pre-opened at each page start/ refresh.

Otherwise it functions as intended.
Any clues?